# Ordered Dithering - Color Values Per Channel

Tags: c#, image-processing, dithering

While moving forward with my algorithm for Ordered Dithering I got a problem, mainly I don't really know what col[levels] might be.

Here is the pseudocode

[image]

k -  number of color values per channel

n - size of the threshold Bayers Matrix

My code which works somehow fine for K = 2, but it doesn't return correct result image when K = 3, K = 4 and so on

**UPDATED CODE**

```
class OrderedDithering
{
    private float[,] bayerMatrix;

    private float[,] dither2x2Matrix =
        new float[,] { { 1, 3 },
                    { 4, 2 } };

    private float[,] dither3x3Matrix =
        new float[,] { { 3, 7, 4 },
                    { 6, 1, 9 },
                     { 2, 8, 5 } };

    public BitmapImage OrderedDitheringApply(BitmapImage FilteredImage, int valuesPerChannel, int thresholdSize)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = ImageConverters.BitmapImage2Bitmap(FilteredImage);

        if (thresholdSize == 2)
        {
            bayerMatrix = new float[2, 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
                    bayerMatrix[i,j] = dither2x2Matrix[i,j] / 5;
        }
        else
        {
            bayerMatrix = new float[3, 3];
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
                    bayerMatrix[i, j] = dither3x3Matrix[i, j] / 10;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.Width; ++i)
            for(int j = 0; j < bitmap.Height; ++j)
            {

                Color color = bitmap.GetPixel(i, j);
                double r = Scale(0, 255, 0, 1, color.R);
                double g = Scale(0, 255, 0, 1, color.G);
                double b = Scale(0, 255, 0, 1, color.B);

                int counter = 0;
                counter += Dither(valuesPerChannel, r, thresholdSize, i, j);
                counter += Dither(valuesPerChannel, g, thresholdSize, i, j);
                counter += Dither(valuesPerChannel, b, thresholdSize, i, j);

                if (counter == 0)
                    bitmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(0,0,0));
                else
                    bitmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(255/counter, 255/counter, 255/counter));
            }

        return ImageConverters.Bitmap2BitmapImage(bitmap);
    }

    public int Dither(int valuesPerChannel, double colorIntensity, int thresholdSize, int i, int j)
    {
        double tempValue = (double)(Math.Floor((double)((valuesPerChannel - 1) * colorIntensity)));
        double re = (valuesPerChannel - 1) * colorIntensity - tempValue;

        if (re >= bayerMatrix[i % thresholdSize, j % thresholdSize])
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public double Scale(double a0, double a1, double b0, double b1, double a)
    {
        return b0 + (b1 - b0) * ((a - a0) / (a1 - a0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a dithering library that works with `System.Drawing` and supports ordered dithering feel free to use [mine](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing). It has an easily usable [`OrderedDitherer`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/?topic=html/T_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_OrderedDitherer.htm) class.

But if you are just playing for the sake of curiosity, and would like to improve your algorithm, here are some comments:

- You now always set the pixels black or white (btw, you can use just `Color.Black` instead of `FromArgb(0, 0, 0)`, for example), so it cannot work for more colors
- It is unclear from the provided code whether a target palette belongs to `colorsNum` but basically you need to quantize all dithered pixels to the nearest transformed color.
- So instead of working by brightness you should apply the ordered matrix for each color channel of each pixels (between the 0..255 range), and pick a color from the target palette for the result. The 'nearest color' can have more interpretation but generally an euclidean search will do it.
- Try to avoid `Bitmap.SetPixel`/`GetPixel` as they are terribly slow and `SetPixel` does not even work with bitmaps that have indexed palette `PixelFormat`.
- Your code does not show the values of your matrix but the values should also be calibrated for the palette you use. The typical default values are good for a BW palette but they are probably too strong for a 256 color palette (the dithering "jumps over" more shades and introduces rather just noise than nice gradients). See [this](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/?topic=html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_OrderedDitherer_ConfigureStrength.htm) page for more info.

Feel free to explore the linked code base. The [Dither](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing/blob/15c7976ed94e313b7c9584c1559c35679f5c08df/KGySoft.Drawing/Drawing/_Extensions/BitmapExtensions.cs#L580) extension method is the starting point for dithering a `Bitmap` in-place, and here are the [OrderedDitherer constructor](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing/blob/15c7976ed94e313b7c9584c1559c35679f5c08df/KGySoft.Drawing/Drawing/Imaging/_Ditherers/OrderedDitherer.cs#L660), the [strength calibration](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing/blob/15c7976ed94e313b7c9584c1559c35679f5c08df/KGySoft.Drawing/Drawing/Imaging/_Ditherers/VariableStrengthDitheringSessionBase.cs#L85) for the min/max values of the matrix and a fairly fast [nearest color search](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing/blob/15c7976ed94e313b7c9584c1559c35679f5c08df/KGySoft.Drawing/Drawing/Imaging/Palette.cs#L304) either by RGB channels or by brightness.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I have changed the code a bit, but I am somehow unsure if it returns proper images now. About your comments: That's true, there was no way of getting more colors, I have changed it now into a new logic and now more shades of gray can be seen. ColorsNum variable is a value that comes from the input, namely number of color values per channel (the naming wasn't good). Is there really a need to use the nearest color searching?

Comment: You can avoid nearest color searching if you can use a fast direct mapping. It is easy for a [grayscale palette](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing/blob/master/KGySoft.Drawing/Drawing/Imaging/_Quantizers/PredefinedColorsQuantizer.cs#L793). The custom mapping function can be passed to the `Palette` class I linked in the answer.